# r twitteR package

Tags: r, twitter

I was reading [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf) of TwitteR package. For `searchTwitter` it says that R returns `A list of status objects`. `status-class` documentation lists several fields and methods.

But as shown below, `class(x)` returns `list`, why? shouldn't it return a status object? Also last two commands dont work, why?

The documentation says that

```
toDataFrame: Converts this into a one row data.frame, with each field 
representing a column.
This can also be accomplished by the S4 style as.data.frame(objectName)


x=searchTwitter("Samsung")
> class(x)
[1] "list"
> abc=as.data.frame(x)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("status", package = "twitteR")" to a data.frame
> x$text
NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `x` is a list of status objects, then the class of `x` is `list`. The class of each element in the list is `status-class`.

You might try something like:

```
class(x[[1]])
```

to check that this is correct.

Similarly, `toDataFrame` acts on objects of class `status-class` - again, the elements of the list, not the list itself.  You might try:

```
toDataFrame(x[[1]])
```

and

```
x[[1]]$text
```

If your aim is to get every element of the list into a single data frame, the function you should be looking at is `twListToDF`.